# Why does DB transaction activity not seem to change despite a cache being active and used?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, redis, mybatis

I hooked up a Redis cache and a PostgreSQL database through MyBatis for a Spring Boot application (REST API). Spring's @Cacheable annotation was used for certain controller routes.

Some stripped down code samples about the cache related parts of the codebase are below (imports and other probably unneeded details omitted):

```java
// App entry point
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.
         run(ApiApplication.class, args);
   }
```

```java
// Cached route
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    // Fetch all users
    @GetMapping("/users")
    @Cacheable("users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers()
    {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    // Empty cache
    @GetMapping("/empty")
    @CacheEvict(value = "users", allEntries = true)
    public void emptyUsersCache() {
        System.out.println("Emptying users cache!");
    }
}
```

```java
// Model
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailId;
}
```

```java
// Repository
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.*;
import net.codinghermit.api.model.User;
import java.util.List;

@Mapper
public interface UserRepository {

    @Select("select * from users")
    public List<User> findAll();


}
```

```yaml
# application.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databasefoo
    username: postgres
    password: foobar
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
server:
  port: 4000
```

Probably relevant dependencies:

`spring-boot-starter-parent` v2.7.4,

`spring-boot-starter-cache` v2.7.4,

`spring-boot-starter-data-redis` v2.7.4,

`mybatis-spring-boot-starter` v2.2.2,

AdoptOpenJDK 16.

I tested with stale data (and the `MONITOR` command in `redis-cli`) to ensure data was actually being pulled from Redis itself.

Yet, when checking with a monitoring tool (DBeaver) the database showed a corresponding hit for each GET request (despite cached data being pulled).

[image: Database hits]

Is this normal behavior?
Am I misunderstanding something basic?
Or is it a sign of a potential misconfiguration somewhere?

Is there a better way to verify whether the cache is being used effectively?

Because the current setup *seems* to work, but I'm not certain if the behavior I'm seeing from the DB is normal.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: What I am seeing in those charts seems compatible with it just being the activity generated by your monitoring tool itself.  Try ramping up your load so the effect of it would be unmistakable.

Comment: @jjanes Yes it's not an ideal screenshot, but I actually timed the spaced GET requests later and the spacing on the chart matched perfectly with them.

It's a weird issue since everything _seems_ to work, but I want to get rid of this nagging doubt to be confident on this.
I was under the impression that when the cache was used (which it _was_ since if I manually edited the DB to make the cache stale and test, it was the stale cache data being pulled), the DB wouldn't be hit _at all._

It could be I completely misunderstood something there though.

Thanks for your time either way.